# .htaccess https rewrite error redirection loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My `.htaccess` code giving me an error `This webpage has a redirect loop` in chrome browser.

Can anyone correct my `.htaccess` code?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^purchase\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.purchase\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/purchase\.com\.au\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

If my website address is purchase.com.au and I need it to redirect to https://purchase.com.au

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Basically what it does is checkes if https is off (request was made via http - no https) and redirect every request to the https variant (same url just goes to https instead of http)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you !!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://purchase.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://purchase.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```